# Angular Material - input field - duplicate fields are displayed

Tags: angular-material, angular5, materialize

I am setting up an Angular project to use the Angular Material framework. I am also using [`materializecss`](https://materializecss.com/). When I try to create a form, I get a double control shown below...

[image: Double outline]

Here is how I am creating this field:

```html
<mat-form-field hintLabel="Max 10 characters" appearance="standard">
  <input matInput #input (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter catalogs">
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either Angular Material MatInput and MatFormField or MaterializeCSS, but not both. They both add their own style to input, causing the problem you see.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. I'll try it out and report back.

Comment: Getting rid of materializeCSS solved the problem. Thank you for your help.